# Redesigned disabled buttons in review are hard to distinguish

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, style

After recent redesign, the buttons in review queue **[No Action Needed]** and **[I'm Done]** look almost the same. I would start competition if you can distinguish which one is disabled on the below image (but I believe the sharp eye of reviewer can find some differences).

Can we get this improved, so the difference is obvious on the first sight?

[image: Ubuntu buttons]

For comparison example screenshot from superuser makes it much easier:

[image]

It is not problem for me, but it might be complicated for new reviewers, since they will not get visual guidance and might get frustrated with non-responsive buttons.

[image]

<sup>*** Yes and I forgot the kitten</sup>

Comment: Yep. In one case, where the comment text had a minimum length, and I'd typed one character too short and hadn't noticed the "1 more character required" line, I just kept clicking on the button  wondering WTF is wrong with it.

Comment: s/more/moar/ :P

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I'll look into the issue.

Comment: @Hynes not sure if related issue on [Unix.SE](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3919/broken-buttons-colors-contrast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this bug. This bug affected a number of Stack Exchange communities, one of which was Ask Ubuntu. The problem arose because the disabled buttons, by default, only changes the `background-color`. For most community designs, this is fine because only a background color is set for buttons. However some communities, such as Ask Ubuntu, use gradients for the button background. This uses the `background` shorthand declaration, which always overrides the background-color.

This should be fixed now. Thanks again for reporting it as it exposed a number of communities which needed corrected.

Comment: And thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Thanks. Looks much better now :) I noticed there was some change on other sites, but only this one attracted my attention.

Comment: Not sure how to contact you better way, but there is hanging one more "design issue" on meta [sec.se](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/broken-css-of-select-your-next-badge-box). Could you have a look also on that one or move it to somebody else who is responsible for the design on sec.se?

Comment: @Jakuje Ok. I made a comment on that thread. Thanks!